# CPU and memory usage increases when read about 10k lines from txt file c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a RangeEnabledObservableCollection bound to ListView source in WPF.

```
public class RangeEnabledObservableCollection<Probe> : ObservableCollection<Probe>
{
    public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<Probe> items)
    {
        
        if (items.Count() <= 0)
        {
            this.Items.Clear();
        }
        foreach (Probe item in items)
        {

            if (!this.Items.Any(r => r.ToString() == item.ToString()))
            {
                this.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
                    
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        this.CheckReentrancy();
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

There is a Filewatcherwatching for changes in the .txt file every 1 second, something like a log file produced by another program. When changes detected, the InsertRange(...) will run to only add new entry from the text file into the collection. This is where I see the CPU usage stay at about 45% and the application becomes unresponsive, the number of lines in the text file reaches about 10k line. Is it because the sorting algorithm not efficient enough? I benchmarked the parser that parse the textfile into a list but it seem fine performance wise.

Once the sorting is done, the UI is called in a Dispatcher to update the ListView Update(). This is where I start to see the memory usage keep going up. Seems like the OnCollectionChanged(...) is doing something with the memory.

This is the method when detected the change in the text file,

```
    private void ReloadProbeList()         
    {
       
       probeCollection.InsertRange(ProjectManager.Instance.CurrentProject.WPR.ProbeList);
        var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            probeCollection.Update();
        });
    }
```

This is the ListView in WPF,

```
<ListView  Name="WorstProbeReportListView" Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding WorstProbeReportDataView}"
               AlternationCount="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FailureType}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding DATAGRID_FAILURE_TYPE, Source={StaticResource GUIResources}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="FailureType"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding DATAGRID_PROBE, Source={StaticResource GUIResources}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="Name"/>                    
                </GridViewColumn>
                <!--GridViewColumn Header="Usage" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Usage}" Width="Auto"/-->
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NodeName}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding DATAGRID_NODE_NAME, Source={StaticResource GUIResources}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="NodeName"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceName}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding DATAGRID_DEVICE_NAME, Source={StaticResource GUIResources}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="DeviceName"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTime}" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding DATAGRID_DATE_TIME, Source={StaticResource GUIResources}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding SortCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="DateTime"/>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
  </ListView>
```

UPDATE*
Updated the InsertRange(...) method, to append new entries instead of adding the whole file from the begining.

```
public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<Probe> items)
    {            
        if (items.Count() <= 0)
        {
            this.Items.Clear();
        }
        for(int i = Items.Count(); i < items.Count() ; i++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(items.ElementAt(i));
        }         
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using telerik's RadGridView that has some of the GUI features I need and it comes with virtualization enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashSet beside the collection that keeps unique elements. This will make the algorithm O(n) instead of O(n²).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0

Another solution is store variable lineNumber, which points to the latest line observed in the log file, that is only if the log file is appended over.

Make sure the Probe object overrides the methods you use for comparison: ToString, GetHashCode, Equals.

Comment: I have gone for the approach to append newly added lines instead of check for equality and avoid duplicates, as I found out that the entries in the log file are already unique by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the implementation of your file parser, we can't review it and help to improve it. Depending on the amount of data changes, maintaining a pointer to the last position in the stream could be sufficient.

In your current implementation the current bottleneck is clearly the UI.

Handling a big item count is not an issue - if you make use of the UI virtualization feature that controls like the `ListView` offer by default.
UI virtualization is a pattern where the items control (its Panel to be precise) controls the item container generation. The idea is to render only the visible items instead of all.
This means instad of your 10K item containers only e.g., 20 are rendered at the time.

Nonetheless, populating an `ItemsControl` with e.g., 10K items at once will impact the performance during the initialization of this control. Although UI virtualization is enabled, the control has to register the items and measure its layout, because for example the `ScrollViewer` needs to know its scroll range. After this initialization routine the UI virtualization will take effect.

When using an `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementation as data source, the refresh time is optimzed, as the `CollectionChanged` event usually reports *only* the new/changed elements - this is how it is designed to be.

Apparently, you have decided to create a custom `ObservableCollection`. That's fine. But you must raise the `CollectionChanged` event properly.
For some reason you have decided to report the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action` as `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`.
If you would have consulted the docs to find the proper [`NotifyCollectionChangedAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction?view=net-6.0#fields) value, you would have learned that `Reset` is the most expensive action to choose:

> "Reset: The contents of the collection changed dramatically"

This means, the changed items (position and count) couldn't be tracked. Therefore, the binding target e.g., the `ListView` will re-initialize itself by clearing its `Items` property and then read the complete `ItemsSource` property again - all 10+K items.

In your case this means, the `ListView` will read all 10+K items from scratch *everytime* a new range of lines arrives or a change is reported i.e. `CollectionChanged` is raised by your `RangeEnabledObservableCollection.Update` method - although you may have only added a single item...

I suggest the following improvements:

- eliminate the sorting. I wonder what you sort when you read from a logfile. In case you read blocks in parallel, then sort the blocks and not the lines (this will reduce the sorted element count significantly).
- configure the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` object properly. This will fix the current performance issue regarding the rendering.
- use an internal `HashSet` to store the `Probe` items. This improves the lookup time significantly (for your performed uniqueness check before inserting new items).
- to ensure data integrity, you must also override the `ObservableCollection.InsertItem` method and check for uniqueness there also.
- to maintain the suggested lookup `HashSet`, you must also override the `InsertItem`, `SetItem`, `RemoveItem` and `ClearItems` methods of `ObservableCollection`.
- use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` instead of the `Dispatcher`. Aside from the obvious synchronization features, `BindigOperations` will also take care to not overload the UI with new changes by applying a throttling algorithm.
- when using the `Dispatcher`, use the modern `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` method instead of the outdated `BeginInvoke` (which is a remainder of the pre TPL era, .NET <4.0 - the member name's prefix "Begin..." indicates this).
- the generic type parameter for the `RangeEnabledObservableCollection` is useless. It doesn't make the collection generic as the type is already hardcoded.
- consider to remove the deferred change notification you have implemented. Currently, `Update` is *directly* called after `InsertRange`. If this is the only use case, then simplify your `RangeEnabledObservableCollection` implementation by calling `ObservableCollection.ClearItems` and `ObservableCollection.InsertItem` directly from within the `InsertRange` method. Those methods will also raise the `CollectionChanged` event properly for you.
- `ObservableCollection` also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So at least raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Count` and the indexer property.

**RangeEnabledObservableCollection.cs**

```cs
public class RangeEnabledObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<Probe>
{
  private List<object> NewItems { get; }
  private List<object> RemovedItems { get; }
  private HashSet<object> InternalItems { get; }
  private bool IsDirty { get; set; }

  public RangeEnabledObservableCollection()
  {
    this.RemovedItems = new List<object>();
    this.NewItems = new List<object>();

    // Optionally store strings if this is reasonable
    // (because you were originally calling Probe.ToString for comparison)
    this.InternalItems = new HashSet<object>();
  }

  public void InsertRangeDeferred(IEnumerable<Probe> items)
  {
    // Items.Count can never be < 0. The original condition is useless.
    if (!items.Any())
    {
      // If the intention is to clear the collection:
      this.RemovedItems.AddRange(this.Items.Cast<object>());

      // Is this really intended?
      this.Items.Clear();
      this.InternalItems.Clear();

      SetPendingState();
      return;
    }

    bool hasChanges = false;
    foreach (Probe item in items)
    {
      if (this.InternalItems.Contains(item))
      {
        continue;
      }

      this.Items.Add(item);
      this.InternalItems.Add(item);
      hasChanges = true;
    }

    if (hasChanges)
    {
      SetPendingState();
    }
  }

  // This method basically updates the layout
  // i.e. notifies the CollectionChanged listeners.
  // Items are already added to the collection,
  // the moment InsertRange is called. I assume this behavior is intentional.
  public void UpdateLayout()
  {
    CheckReentrancy();
    if (!this.IsDirty)
    {
      return;
    }

    var changeAction = this.NewItems.Any() 
      ? NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add 
      : NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove;
    var changedItems = changeAction == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add 
      ? this.NewItems 
      : this.RemovedItems;

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Count));
    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionChanged(changeAction, changedItems);

    ClearPendingState();
  }

  protected override void InsertItem(int index, Probe item)
  {
    CheckReentrancy();
    if (this.InternalItems.Contains(item))
    {
      return;
    }

    base.InsertItem(index, item);
    this.InternalItems.Add(item);

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Count));
    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
  }

  protected override void SetItem(int index, Probe item)
  {
    CheckReentrancy();
    if (this.InternalItems.Contains(item))
    {
      return;
    }

    Probe oldItem = this[index];
    base.SetItem(index, item);
    this.InternalItems.Remove(oldItem);
    this.InternalItems.Add(item);

    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, oldItem, item, index);
  }

  protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
  {
    CheckReentrancy();
    Probe removedItem = this[index];

    base.RemoveItem(index);
    this.InternalItems.Remove(removedItem);

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Count));
    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removedItem, index);
  }

  protected override void ClearItems()
  {
    CheckReentrancy();
    base.ClearItems();
    this.InternalItems.Clear();

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Count));
    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionReset();
  }

  private void SetPendingState()
  {
    this.IsDirty = true;
  }

  private void ClearPendingState()
  {
    this.IsDirty = false;
    this.NewItems.Clear();
    this.RemovedItems.Clear();
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private void OnCollectionReset()
  {
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction changeAction, IList changedItems)
  {

    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(changeAction, changedItems));
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item, int index)
  {
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index));
  }

  private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object oldItem, object newItem, int index)
  {
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem, index));
  }
}
```

**Append new lines**

```cs
private void ReloadProbeList()         
{
  probeCollection.InsertRangeDeferred(ProjectManager.Instance.CurrentProject.WPR.ProbeList);
  probeCollection.UpdateLayout();
}
```

### Remarks

If the deferred notification is not required (splitting up inserting a range of `Probe` items and raising the event) then remove the `UpdateLayout`, `SetPendingState` and `ClearPendingState` methods from the example. In `InsertRange` simply don't reference the internal `Items` collection. Rather call `ClearItems` and `InsertItem` instead. Those protected members of `ObservableCollection` will automatically raise the proper `CollectionChanged` and `PropertyChanged` events for operation. Your posted code does not justify the added complexity by implementing such a deferring notification behavior. Instead it introduces a bug potential. This behavior is completely controlled by the client of the collection. If somebody forgets to call the Update method the observers will never get notified. At least consider to rename the API, for example `BeginInsertRange` and `EndInsertRange`.

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy explanation, I did not had to chance to trying out all of them. It turns out when grouping is applied, the UI virtualization is disabled for some reason so i set the VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" to bring back that virtualization and it helps a little.